# draw salts and ions with education purposes

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

I want to draw some schematic representations of salts for educational purposes. The figure shows a example which can be generated with the metapost code below. I would like to improve the draws in two ways: first) round the corners of the rectangles; second) improve the triangular slots i.e. the interaction zones (better alignment and other didactic improvements)

The code can generate every kind of salt: Salt(anionCharge, cationCharge, anionName, cationName);

[image]

```
\starttext

\startalignment[middle]
\dontleavehmode
\startMPcode
vardef Ionic (expr p,  n, w, o) = 
pair vec ; path pat;
 if o==1:
 pat := for i=1 upto n: (w,i)--(w,i+.2)--(w/2,i+.35)--(w, i+.60)--endfor(w,n+.8)--(w/2-.2,n+.8)--(w/2-.2,1)--cycle;
else:
 pat := for i=1 upto n: (w,i)--(w,i+.2)--(w/2,i+.35)--(w, i+.60)--endfor(w,n+.8)--(w+w/2+.2,n+.8)--(w+w/2+.2,1)--cycle;
fi;
 pat xscaled 40 yscaled 40
enddef;

def Salt(expr anionCharge, cationCharge, anionName, cationName) =
 path catiao, aniao;
 numeric ania, catia;
 ania := anionCharge; catia := cationCharge;
 catiao := Ionic((0,0),catia,1,1);
   for i=1 upto ania:
      draw catiao shifted (0,(i-1)*40*catia) withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor red;
      fill catiao shifted (0,(i-1)*40*catia) withcolor 0.7white;
      label.lft(cationName, (0,i*40*catia));
   endfor;
 aniao := Ionic((0,0),ania,1,0);
   for i=1 upto catia:
      draw aniao shifted (10,(i-1)*40*ania) withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor blue;
      fill aniao shifted (10,(i-1)*40*ania) withcolor .9white;
      label.rt(anionName, (85,i*40*ania));
   endfor;
enddef;

Salt(3,2,btex PO$_4^{3-}$ etex, btex Ca$^{2+}$ etex);
\stopMPcode
\stopalignment


\stoptext
```

Comment: I know veeery different kind of salts.

Comment: Nice for you. For me, I'm glad if my students write well the structure of few salts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## New Answer

Actually I prefer circle over rectangle

[image]

```
\tikzset{
    c/.style={violet},
    a/.style={olive},
    er/.store in=\er,er=.2,
    nodes={white,font=\Huge}
}
\def\msm#1#2{\pgfmathsetmacro#1{#2}\xdef#1{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\salt{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\saltopt}{\saltopt[]}}
\def\saltopt[#1]#2^#3+#4Å#5^#6-#7Å{{
    \tikzset{#1,#2/.try,#5/.try}
    \msm\cc{max(#3.0,1)}\msm\ac{max(#6.0,1)}
    \msm\tt{\cc*\ac/gcd(\cc,\ac)}\msm\htt{floor(\tt/2)+1}
    \msm\cn{\tt/\cc}\msm\an{\tt/\ac}
    \msm\cr{#4}\msm\ar{#7}\msm\tr{\ar+\cr}
    % prepare center ions, four cases
    \ifodd\an\ifodd\cn % both odd
        \xdef\cx{-\cr}\xdef\cy{0}\xdef\ax{\ar}\xdef\ay{0}
        \fill[c](\cx,\cy)circle(\cr)node(C0){$\mathrm{#2}^{#3+}$};
        \fill[a](\ax,\ay)circle(\ar)node(A0){$\mathrm{#5}^{#6-}$};
    \else % anion number odd
        \msm\cx{\ar-sqrt(\tr*\tr-\cr*\cr)}\msm\cy{\cr}\xdef\ax{\ar}\xdef\ay{0}
        \fill[c](\cx,\cy)circle(\cr)node(C+0){$\mathrm{#2}^{#3+}$}(\cx,-\cy)circle(\cr)node(C-0){$\mathrm{#2}^{#3+}$};
        \fill[a](\ax,\ay)circle(\ar)node(A0){$\mathrm{#5}^{#6-}$};
    \fi\else % cation number odd
        \xdef\cx{-\cr}\xdef\cy{0}\msm\ax{sqrt(\tr*\tr-\ar*\ar)-\cr}\msm\ay{\ar}
        \fill[c](\cx,\cy)circle(\cr)node(C0){$\mathrm{#2}^{#3+}$};
        \fill[a](\ax,\ay)circle(\ar)node(A+0){$\mathrm{#5}^{#6-}$}(\ax,-\ay)circle(\ar)node(A-0){$\mathrm{#5}^{#6-}$};
    \fi
    % draw ions and electrons
    \xdef\ao{0}\xdef\co{0}\xdef\eo{0}
    \foreach\e in{\htt,...,\tt}{
        \msm\am{mod(\e,\ac)}\msm\cm{mod(\e,\cc)}
        % need new electron
            \msm\para{\ar+(2*\eo+1)*\er}
            \msm\ex{\ax+\para*(\cx-\ax)/\tr}
            \msm\ey{\ay+\para*(\cy-\ay)/\tr}
            \msm\eo{int(\eo+1)}
            \ifdim\ey pt=0pt
                \fill[a](\ex,\ey)circle(\er)node(e00\eo){};
                \ifodd\tt\ifnum\eo>1
                    \msm\eo{int(\eo+1)}
                    \fill[a](\ex-2*\er,\ey)circle(\er)node(e00\eo){};
                \fi\else
                    \msm\eo{int(\eo+1)}
                    \fill[a](\ex-2*\er,\ey)circle(\er)node(e00\eo){};
                \fi
            \else
                \fill[a](\ex,\ey)circle(\er)node(e+\ao+\co+\eo){}(\ex,-\ey)circle(\er)node(e-\ao-\co-\eo){};
            \fi
        \ifdim\e pt<\tt pt
        \ifdim\am pt=0pt % need new anion
            \msm\para{2*\ar*\ar/\tr}
            \msm\perp{sqrt(4*\ar*\ar-\para*\para)}
            \msm\axnew{\ax+(\para*(\cx-\ax)+\perp*(\cy-\ay))/\tr}
            \msm\aynew{\ay+(\para*(\cy-\ay)+\perp*(\ax-\cx))/\tr}
            \xdef\ax{\axnew}\xdef\ay{\aynew}
            \msm\ao{int(\ao+1)}\xdef\eo{0}
            \fill[a](\ax,\ay)circle(\ar)node(A+\ao){$\mathrm{#5}^{#6-}$}(\ax,-\ay)circle(\ar)node(A-\ao){$\mathrm{#5}^{#6-}$};
        \else\ifdim\cm pt=0 pt % need new cation
            \msm\para{2*\cr*\cr/\tr}
            \msm\perp{sqrt(4*\cr*\cr-\para*\para)}
            \msm\cxnew{\cx+(\para*(\ax-\cx)+\perp*(\cy-\ay))/\tr}
            \msm\cynew{\cy+(\para*(\ay-\cy)+\perp*(\ax-\cx))/\tr}
            \xdef\cx{\cxnew}\xdef\cy{\cynew}
            \msm\co{int(\co+1)}\xdef\eo{0}
            \fill[c](\cx,\cy)circle(\cr)node(C+\co){$\mathrm{#2}^{#3+}$}(\cx,-\cy)circle(\cr)node(C-\co){$\mathrm{#2}^{#3+}$};
        \fi\fi\fi
    }
}}
\tikz{\salt Xk^ +2Å Cd^ -3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^2+2Å Cd^2-3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^3+2Å Cd^3-3Å}

\tikz{\salt Xk^1+2Å Cd^2-3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^2+2Å Cd^4-3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^3+2Å Cd^6-3Å}

\tikz{\salt Xk^ +2Å Cd^3-3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^ +2Å Cd^4-3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^ +2Å Cd^5-3Å}

\tikz{\salt Xk^2+2Å Cd^3-3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^2+2Å Cd^5-3Å}
\tikz{\salt Xk^2+2Å Cd^7-3Å}
```

Collection of salts

[image]

```
\tikz{
    \salt                            Xk^2+3Å Cd^ -2Å
    \salt[shift={(12,0)}]            Xk^4+3Å Cd^3-2Å
    \salt[shift={(-4,15)},rotate=-60]Xk^6+3Å Cd^5-2Å
    \salt[shift={(-6,-18)},rotate=60]Xk^8+3Å Cd^7-2Å
}
```

A huge salt

```
\tikz{\salt[rotate=90]Xk^29+12Å Cd^12-5Å}
```

[image]

---

The canonical way to adjust the size of ions is to specify it directly in

```
\salt[er=.2]Xk^29+12Å Cd^12-5Å
```

Where `12Å` and `5Å` is then translated to `12cm` and `5cm`. `Å` comes from [angstrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom), as you probably had guessed it. To adjust the size of electron, pass `er=.2` in the option.

Since I added an optional argument to `\salt`, you can pass any Ti*k*Z styles to it. As shown above it could be `shift=` and `rotate`. It could also be `scale=`, `c/.style=` or color/font specification.

You may, in addition, add `\tikzset{Xk/.style={c/.style=black}}` so that every time `Xk` is drawn, it is colored black.

---

## Old Answer

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \def\salt#1^#2+#3^#4-{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\cationcharge{max(0#2,1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\anioncharge{max(0#4,1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\totaltransfer{\cationcharge*\anioncharge/gcd(\cationcharge,\anioncharge)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\halftransfer{max(\totaltransfer/2,2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\anionnumber{\totaltransfer/\anioncharge}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\cationnumber{\totaltransfer/\cationcharge}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\w{.1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{.1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{.2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\z{.5}
        \tikz{
            % draw anion
            \foreach\c in{1,...,\cationnumber}
                \fill[rounded corners,yellow](-\w,\c*\cationcharge)+(0,-\x)rectangle node[black]{$\mathrm{#1}^{#2+}$}+(-\halftransfer,-\cationcharge+\x);
            % draw cation
            \foreach\a in{1,...,\anionnumber}
                \fill[rounded corners,lime](\w,\a*\anioncharge)+(0,-\x)rectangle node[black]{$\mathrm{#3}^{#4-}$}+(\halftransfer,-\anioncharge+\x);
            % draw transfer
            \foreach\e in{1,...,\totaltransfer}{
                \fill[white](-\w,\e-.5)+(0,\y)--+(-\z,0)--+(0,-\y);
                \fill[lime](\w,\e-.5)+(0,\y)--+(-\z,0)--+(0,-\y);
            }
        }
    }
    \salt Na^+Cl^-
    \salt Ca^2+Cl^-
    \salt Ca^2+SO_4^2-
    \salt Ca^2+PO_4^3-
```

Or this

[image]

```
\def\salt#1^#2+#3^#4-{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cationcharge{max(0#2,1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\anioncharge{max(0#4,1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\totaltransfer{\cationcharge*\anioncharge/gcd(\cationcharge,\anioncharge)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\halftransfer{max(\totaltransfer/2,2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\anionnumber{\totaltransfer/\anioncharge}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cationnumber{\totaltransfer/\cationcharge}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\w{.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\x{.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\z{.2}
    \tikz{
        % draw anion
        \foreach\c in{1,...,\cationnumber}
            \fill[rounded corners,yellow](-\w,\c*\cationcharge)+(0,-\x)rectangle node[black]{$\mathrm{#1}^{#2+}$}+(-\halftransfer,-\cationcharge+\x);
        % draw transfer
        \foreach\e in{1,...,\totaltransfer}{
            \fill[white](-\w,\e-.5)+(-\y,0)circle(\z);
            \fill[lime](\w,\e-.5)+(-\y,0)circle(\z);
        }
        % draw cation
        \foreach\a in{1,...,\anionnumber}
            \fill[rounded corners,lime](\w,\a*\anioncharge)+(0,-\x)rectangle node[black]{$\mathrm{#3}^{#4-}$}+(\halftransfer,-\anioncharge+\x);
    }
}
\salt Na^+Cl^-
\salt Ca^2+Cl^-
\salt Ca^2+SO_4^2-
\salt Ca^2+PO_4^3-
```

Comment: I would like  to add some emotional content to each ion to improve the memory (Papez circuit). Perhaps adding a specific  background image to each ion representation.  In this case the salt function call should be \salt Na^+Cl- NaImage ClImage.

Comment: @Jorge Well, If the image of element `Xy` is always `XyImage.png` then you can replace `node{$\mathrm{#1}^{#2+}$}` by `node{\includegraphics{#1.png}}`. No need the fifth and sixth arguments.

Comment: Thanks again.  I found a little bug when a call \salt Ca^2+SO_4^2-. In this call tikz draw two calcium sulphate molecules. I think  that the \totaltransfer should be the Least Common Multiple and not the product of the anion and cation valences.

Comment: @Jorge I forgot most of the details... But is not it possible to have `\totaltransfer` a multiple of the lcm?

Comment: The circles are a great idea. Amazing solution. Thanks again.

Comment: A small suggestion: its a great improvement if the dots can represent the extra electrons in the anion side. In this way the dots color should be the olive color and their representation should be in the cation circles. Another question: how can I scale down the size of the  pict?

Comment: In the representation of the interaction between Ca2+ and SO_42- I have only one dot. The same happens in every interaction between 2+ and 2- species. In the interaction between 3+ and 3- I have two dots (should be 3), and so on. +1, -1 (one dot, correct); +2, -2 (1 dot, incorrect, should be 2 dots); +3, -3 (2 dots, incorrect, should be 3 dots).

Comment: All my requests are done. Thanks very much.